# Getting apiData more than 1000 objects in an array is getting stuck. Is there any optimize way?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, angular, user-interface, frontend

```
 useEffect(() => {
        const tableWorker = new Worker(URL.createObjectURL(new Blob([`(${editInputData.toString()})()`])));
        tableWorker.postMessage({ planData });
        tableWorker.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
            const { param1, param2 } = e.data;
            let columns = Array.isArray(param1) ? param1?.reduce((acc, curr, index) => {
                return acc = [...acc, { header: curr, accessorKey: index + 1, id: index + 1 }]
            }, []) : [];

            setColumns([...columns]);

            let tablesData = Array.isArray(param2) ? param2?.map((data) => {
                let numberOfInputs = columns?.reduce((acc, curr) => {
                    return acc = {
                        ...acc, [curr?.accessorKey]: <input name={`${data}_${curr?.header}`} style={{ width: '50px' }} />
                    }
                }, {});
                return {
                    'dept': data,
                    ...numberOfInputs
                }
            }) : [];
            
            setTableData([...tablesData]);
        })
    }, [])


// worker.js file code

export function editInputData() {
    self.addEventListener('message', (e) => { /* eslint-disable-line no-restricted-globals */
        if (!e) return;
        
        const { planData } = e.data;

        const param1 = Array.isArray(planData?.result?.PARAMETERS) ? planData?.result?.PARAMETERS?.map((option) => option.PARAM1_NAME) : [];
        const param2 = Array.isArray(planData?.result?.PARAMETERS) ? planData?.result?.PARAMETERS?.map((option) => option.PARAM2_NAME) : [];

        postMessage({ param1, param2 });
    });
}
```

After fetching data, page is getting stuck while looping and creating the dynamic inputs. Is there a way or optimize the loop to create thousand of input without getting my page stuck

Answer (score 0):

**Best fix** is, if you control the server
is to paginate the data (you can find tons of tons of information about api pagination)
you always ask for 10-30 items or how much you think is good for you (should be low)

You can also save this in `useMemo` but I don't think it's a good solution
because I can't see any scenario which someone needs to see a 1000 inputs

if this is a public api there should be an option of pagination if it's your api code implement one, again you can find a lot of examples online.